# Convert HEX String to UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata

I have some request that returns a JSON string as the response.

I use the Alamofire framework, and in the function where I parse the JSON response:

```
if let img = jsonData["my_data"]["img"].string{
   printl(img)
}
```

After that, I get the description

```
img = "\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"
```

I need to convert this string into a `UIImage`. I tried doing it using the following code:

```
if let img = jsonData["status_order"]["img"].string {
    let myData = img.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    // println(myData)
    let base64String = myData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.allZeros)
    // println(base64String)
    let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    var decodedimage = UIImage(data: decodedData!)
    println(decodedimage)
    my_pic.image = decodeimage // I get nil
}
```

But after that I get some errors:

> 2015-09-18 18:57:14.363 taxi-admin[1520:3e03] ERROR: unable to get the
>   receiver data from the DB!
>
> 2015-09-18 18:57:16.822 taxi-admin[1520:4e03] ERROR:
>   ForceShrinkPersistentStore_NoLock -delete- We do not have a BLOB or
>   TEXT column type.  Instead, we have 5.

Comment: This string is not in base64 representation, it just has byte sequence. You need to convert it to `NSData` by other way. Look at this [`fromHexString`](https://github.com/CryptoCoinSwift/RIPEMD-Swift/blob/master/Classes/NSData%2BHexString.swift) function.

Comment: Alexandr, seams that string have weird format. Init image with this HEX data give nil value.